# "Variable not assigned" for variable that is never used (I think)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

so I have this piece of code where I have a serialized prefab, which I then instantiate. I then do some stuff with the instance. However, when I run the game, I get an error that says a variable of the prefab itself has not been assigned, even though I only use the instance. Sorry if I don't explain it well, hopefully the code makes it a little more clear:

Prefab gets initialized:

```
[SerializeField] MeshGenerator meshGenerator;
```

Prefab gets instantiated a bunch of times, then all instances get put in a list:

```
for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
            {
                //Removed some unimportant code here to make it more readable

                var mesh = Instantiate(meshGenerator, new Vector3(100, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                meshes.Add(mesh); //Add the mesh to a list
            }
        }
```

Then I do some modifications to the meshes' vertices (for another part of the program), and finally for each mesh I throw the following function:

```
public void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
```

The lines "mesh.Clear()", "mesh.vertices = vertices" and "mesh.RecalculateNormals()" are the ones throwing the errors, the console says that the "mesh" variable of the prefab shown at the very beginning (meshGenerator) has not been assigned, even though I only use the instances, not the prefab itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: sorry I forgot to mention that the "mesh" variable gets initialized in the "MeshGenerator" script.

Comment: These are in a different method ... You probably want to remove the `var` in `var mesh = ...` however it will then anyway only be the last assigned value after the loop ... Don't you rather want to iterate over all meshes in your list?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an instance of the mesh you want to change as a parameter in the `UpdateMesh()` method. Without passing `mesh` as a parameter the game engine will assume `mesh` is a field or property in the `MonoBehavior` script.

```cs
public void UpdateMesh(Mesh mesh)
{
    mesh.Clear();

    mesh.triangles = triangles;

    mesh.SetVertices(vertices);
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
}
```

Side note, just for clarification, unless `triangles` and `vertices` are fields / properties, you should consider passing those as parameters as well, since the compiler won't know where to find them unless they're a field/prop or passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I could simply call the `UpdateMesh()` function in its own script, and now everything works.